# Multiple minecraft accounts and cost?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have 4 kids and they all want to play minecraft together. I know from research on here that I will need 4 accounts but do they cost money? If so, how much do it cost per account? (I will I need 3 Androids and a window 10 pc)? Is it monthly or yearly or a one time cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you'll need to do is actually buy the game. On android, it is $6.99 (USD), and on PC, it is $26.99 (USD). You need to buy minecraft for 4 devices, to play with 4 people. After that, you can sign in with a microsoft account by selecting "Microsoft Account" to the bottom right of the home screen. Then, follow the instructions from there. You need to have 1 Microsoft account for each device, and if you dont have them already, you can find out how to make them by following the instructions (you will be able to find out how to make an account on the Microsoft Account screen).

Microsoft accounts are free to use.

Comment: but Microsoft is a computer "system" so can I sign into Microsoft accounts on a Samsung tablets?

Comment: Yes! You can pretty much sign in with a microsoft account on pretty much any minecraft bedrock edition device.

Comment: so I have to pay $47.00 USD to get my children minecraft forever?

Comment: Pretty much. If you have a video game console, then you can actually play split screen mode by connecting another controller, therefore saving money. I believe you can play up to 4 people on one screen. 47 dollars for minecraft is pretty much worth it, because you can do so much in the game, and its still cheaper than most video games.

Comment: we don't have a gaming console and so it's cheaper for us to buy it on 4 devices.

Comment: how do I create Microsoft accounts?

Comment: Go to this link and follow the directions there:
https://signup.live.com/?lic=1

Comment: Thx u! I will do that